# Replacement charger

Tags: windows, charger

I recently damaged my Lenovo laptop charger and now I'm trying to find a replacement and I have only found one similar charger with my original one on Amazon there all specifications match input voltage output voltage etc there output ampere also match but there input ampere differs my original charger have 1.8a whereas the other charger have 1.5a on input. So can I use the new one or not?

Comment: Which laptop are we talking about? And which charger would you like to buy?

Comment: I'm talking about Lenovo IdeaPad slim 3 and my original charger specs are  Output: 20 V, 3.25 A ,65W Input: 100-240 V, ~1.8 A, 50-60 Hz